# CLRS 4th edition mergeSort termination conditon (question 2.3-2)

Tags: mergesort

Question (corrected based on ERATA):
The test in line 1 of the mergeSort procedure reads `if p >= r` rather than `if p == r.`
If mergeSort is called with p > r, then the subarray A[p:r] is empty.
Argue that as long as the initial call of `mergeSort(A, 1, n)` has `n >= 1`, the test `if p == r` suffices to ensure that no recursive call has `p > r`.

```
Edit: The given code below should be seen as pseudo-code (not python). Array indices start from 1.

def mergeSort(arr, p, r):
    if p >= r:                  #line 1
        return                  #line 2
    q = math.floor((p+r)/2)     #line 3
    mergeSort(arr, p, q)        #line 4
    mergeSort(arr, q+1, r)      #line 5
                                #line 6
    merge(arr, p, q, r)         #line 7
```

My attempt at solution:
For line 4, p is always less than or equal to r based on the initial conditions and the fact, that q is a midpoint between p and r.
I run into problem for line 5, if I had an array with single element then line 4 is good but for line 5, q+1 leads to p > r
What am I missing?

Edit: Based on comments today, it makes perfect sense to replace `p>=r` with `p==r`. there are two function calls to itself within the function. line 4 call used p and q as parameters. since q is a midpoint between p and r (with r >=p always), p can never be greater than q for line 4. for same reasons, q is always less than r and thus q+1 can only be equal to r at max. this reasoning make perfect sense and is quite apparent. i think i was just tired when i wrote this question.

Comment: The call should probably be `mergeSort(A, 0, n-1)`.

Comment: @rcgldr I don't know who "dostonnabotov" is, but they're none of CLRS, so that has the same issues. I don't know about browsers vs viruses, but there'd still be the danger of false negatives. Anyway, yeah, that *whole* error doesn't matter, as it was already fixed. If you meant that *the OP* should change the call *in a Python translation*... Ok, maybe, although I'd then likely also use an exclusive upper bound as is standard in Python.

Comment: @nocomment - I deleted prior comments. Github is based in San Fransico. I don't know the origins of the pdf version of the book. The [errata](https://mitp-content-server.mit.edu/books/content/sectbyfn/books_pres_0/11599/e4-bugs.html) is from MIT.  The correction the OP mentions is listed as a correction for page 44 of the book. You've already correctly answered the OP"s question. However, most library merge sort implementation use indexes (0,n), such as C++ begin() and end() member functions of container classes.

Comment: @rcgldr So there's no crime in San Francisco? :-). Btw I just saw that [the book's page](https://mitpress.mit.edu/9780262046305/introduction-to-algorithms/) offers Python code, and sadly they did go with an inclusive upper bound, causing multiple annoying `-1` and `+1`. I guess they wanted to stay as close to their pseudo-code as possible. Anyway, my point was that the top call isn't in the SO question's code, it's only in the quoted question from the book, so it looked like you meant that, and changing that would be inappropriate.

Comment: @nocomment - San Francisco - unlike some foreign countries, the publishers could sue to have that pdf file removed. As for the python code:  `def merge_sort(A, p=0, r=None): |  ... | if r is None: r = len(A) - 1`, so the default parameters are 0 and len(A)-1, which I what I mentioned in my original comment.  Although this is useful for academic purposes, the original merge sort is bottom up , and almost all library implementations are a hybrid of insertion sort and bottom up merge sort, such as TimSort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I had an array with single element then ...

then `p == r` and you return in line 2 and don't reach line 5.

Comment: i think this answer is incorrect. you return from the callee function after call made by line 4 but then line 5 attempt at making another call. line 5 call is made with q+1 so that  would that not put p > r?

Comment: @sam Hmm, I'm not sure what your confusion is. Do you maybe not understand what `return` means? You don't get to line 4, either.

Comment: i think you are confused and perhaps don't understand recursion. return doesn't mean returning control to topmost function call in stack. it is simply returning control to the calling function.

Comment: @sam I understand recursion perfectly well. The only thing I'm confused about is your confusion :-). And it doesn't even matter here where control goes. It only matters that it **doesn't** continue after line 2. How do you think `p > r` could happen? Can you give an explicit example with numbers instead of variables? Maybe then I can tell where you're mistaken.

Comment: question asks if you could replace line 2 with ```p == r``` and still have function run perfectly. lets say you call function with ```arr = [5, 4], p = 1 and r = 2 ``` Keep in mind that indices start from 1. now if condition is false for first call with given parameter and function computes q = 1 and then calls itself with ```arr=[5,4], p = 1 and r = 1```. the callee for line 4 returns control to caller as ```p==r```. then line 5 gets triggered within the same original caller function for  ```arr=[5,4], p = q +1 = 2 and r = 1``` for this line 5 call, now you end up with stack overflow

Comment: @sam Ok, that's what I suspected. You think there's a single global variable `r`, right? That's not the case. Every call has its own `r` variable. When the line 4 call returns, line 5 doesn't have `r = 1`. It's still `r = 2`. It was `r = 1` only inside the call from line 4. That does not affect the `r` of the caller.

Comment: ah dang it, your are right. i failed to register that line 5 is being called with q and r. I don't why i kept r =1 even though that makes no sense now that you pointed it out. this makes me feel so dumb. i forgot the original r was 2 and not 1 as in line 4. even though it was right in front of me. thank you.